# Replacing static header image on my blogger template

Tags: html, image, header, blogger

I've uploaded the Blogger theme 'Scratch-green' (free version) - does anybody know how I can replace the default header image to one of my own. The theme links to [this template](http://themes.teamkraftt.com/harmony/classic/)  and I just want to replace the header image to my own. Have tried altering various parts of the html and other suggestions found on Google but nothing seems to work!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you have to replace the `src` to your own image source location.

From the image you provided, the current `src` is:

```
<img alt="Harmony Clean Flat reaponsive. . . "
     class="logo-black" 
     src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/...." />
```

Change the `src` to the location of your image and change the `alt`to an alternative text to show in case the image resource is not found:

```
<img alt="a_description_of_your_image_header_or_website"
     class="logo-black" 
     src="http://the_url_to_your_image" />
```

Hopefully this helps, good luck!

> could not load template preview: error parsing xml.

Seems like your webpage is being treated like `xml`.

1. Try setting your `content-type="text/html"` explicitly
2. Often when you provide `url`s to external resources (in this case your header image), if your `src` contains  special characters you have to write them a different way:

e.g:

- **&**  has to be replaced with `&amp;`
- **>** has to be replaced with `&gt;`

**SO if your url looks something like:**

```
src="http://example.header&logo-image.jpg"
```

replace it like this:

```
src="http://example.header&amp;logo-image.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks @esteban rincon tried that originally but comes up with the error msg 'could not load template preview: error parsing xml.... the reference to entity "feat" must end with the ':' delimeter.' Not quite sure what that means!! Thanks anyway though! Wondering if I need to be looking somewhere else within the code!

Comment: @JamieEdmondson, take a look at the answer again, I've added some additional info regarding your  **error msg**

Comment: Thanks @esteban rincon I figured out that I was not putting the right url image address (hadn't shared it properly - doh!). Thanks anyway for your time and feedback though, much appreciated